# Math in titles on the main page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

Math in titles seems not to be rendered now on the main page.

Comment: It's working for me. Have you tried doing a hard refresh (Shift+Refresh on Firefox) or clearing your cache?

Comment: /me sighs. Surely there is *some* way of not having the masses read meta for cues on when to clear the cache?

Comment: @Rahul: what do you mean by "shift + refresh"?  The titles do not display properly for me, either.  Manually deleting the cache does not seem to help.

Comment: @Mariano: I'm not sure I understand your comment; did clearing the cache solve the problem for you? @Ryan: Hold down Shift and (a) click the Refresh button, or (b) press Ctrl+R. It's strange, though, as far as I know manually deleting the cache should have had the same effect...

Comment: None of that works, in particular there is no "refresh" button on my computer.  Clearing the cache and CTRL+R, neither make any substantial changes to the presentation of the page.

Comment: @Rahul: my comment expressed the frustration at this being the only site I visit where periodically I have to clear the cache, after reading here that that fixes some problem! :)

Comment: @Mariano: Which operating system are you using?  I'm running Ubuntu 8.10.  I'm curious if this is OS-specific.

Comment: @Mariano: It was more of a precautionary suggestion, along the lines of "Is your computer plugged in and turned on?" :) -- it feels a little condescending to ask, but is worth asking once. I think we have to bear with some occasional forced refreshing right now while the design of the site is still in flux. It should get better once the site design settles down.

Comment: @Ryan, an up to date Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried clearing the cache in Firefox. Also discovered that a "hard refresh" in Firefox for Linux is a CTRL-F5, and it also does not fix the rendering problem.

It appears the "active" button is causing the cropping in the thread titles, as in both Meta and the parent site, the titles are cropped just before the column that the active button sits in.

2nd edit: at the bottom of the page under the list of thread titles there's a horizontal slider bar.  So I can scroll to the bottom of the page and use the slider to read the other half of the thread titles.  Seems rather inefficient.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running?

Comment: @Rahul: 3.6.11 .

Comment: You should start a new question for those bugs/feature-requests that are not relevant to "math in titles on the main page".